# How do I take a javascript function and change an image on 3 separate time intervals onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Scenario :**

- I currently have a background image which is a gif. As a cool transition, I would like to edit the image on click of a button.
- I found this really awesome pixelation function on code pen:
  https://codepen.io/crosslab/pen/ZLJxRj.
- I was hoping the user could on click on a button and 3 stages of this pixel effect to the image. 
  For example; at 300ms 30% pixelated, 600ms 60% pixelated and 900ms 90% pixelated.

How can I do this?
 I am also open for any other suggestions on how I could create this effect, potentially any more distorted effects would be awesome. 
For example, this other pen has a cool effect: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrMOWV

Thanks for taking a look!

```
<div class="footage">
</div>

<button class="menu1">
  <p class="">
    GO!
  </p>
</button>

.footage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url(https://media1.giphy.com/media/17qXCJ8dGZHjy/giphy.gif?cid=3640f6095c14c459364b487a410e8fa3);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 5vw;
}
```

Comment: don't you care about any answer ? - why ? -

Answer (score 0):

by using setInterval / clearInterval...

```js
var
  ref_Interval   = 0, 
  TimeDuration   = 0,
  clickStage     = 0
  ;      
const
  TimeLapsStep   = 100,  // ms
  TimeLimit      = 10000,
  info_TimeLapse = document.querySelector('#TimeLapse > span')
  ;
 
document.getElementById('TimingButton').onclick = function()
{
  switch (clickStage)
  {
    case 0:
        TimeDuration = 0;
        clearInterval(ref_Interval);
        ref_Interval = setInterval(TimeLapse_indent,TimeLapsStep);

        info_TimeLapse.textContent = '0ms, started...';
        clickStage++;
        break;
    case 1:
        info_TimeLapse.textContent = TimeDuration.toString() + 'ms, 1st stage.';
        clickStage++;
        break;
    case 2:
        clearInterval(ref_Interval);
        info_TimeLapse.textContent = TimeDuration.toString() + 'ms, 2nd stage - end.';
        clickStage   = 0;
        break;
  }
}
    
function TimeLapse_indent()
{
    TimeDuration+=TimeLapsStep;
    if (TimeDuration > TimeLimit)
    {
      clearInterval(ref_Interval);
      clickStage = 0;
      info_TimeLapse.textContent = 'out of Limit (' + TimeLimit.toString() + 'ms), stoped.';
    }
}
```

```html
    <div id="TimeLapse"> time lapse = <span>none</span></div>

    <button id="TimingButton">TimingButton</button>
```